# Reload a part of page using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does anyone have any idea how can I reload a specific part of a page when pressing a customized refresh button in React?

Can anyone also give an example?

Thanks!

**My code:**

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  products: this.props.productData //where productData an array of all products-ID
 };
 this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
}

refresh() {
  this.setState({ products: null });
  this.forceUpdate();
}

render() {
  const { products } = this.state;
        <Button onClick={this.refresh} />
        <ListComponent
          data={products.map(entry => ({
            text: entry.productId
          }))}
        />
  );
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Comment: @AndrewL see my post above.

Comment: Sweet. I have retracted my downvote. So yeah, you want the `#data` div or the `progressBar` div to reload? And where is the button for toggling the reload?

Comment: @AndrewL I forgot to add the Button. See above! I want to reload the #data div.

Comment: @AndrewL I edited again my code. Can u please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is actually how you are supposed to do it, but here is a hack that I use,

Put the div in a property in the state(let's call it `element`). Then, when you are calling `refreshFunction ()`, change what's in `this.state.element` with an empty `div` (or a custom made `div` that should show while you fetch the new data). After you've fetched the new data, put it back in `this.state.element`, and update any other property that you need.

Comment: Sorry but this hack does not work for me. I want a real solution. Thanks btw.

Comment: What's the data that you need to update. If you don't have to modify the JSX by refreshing, you can just keep your data in the state. When you fetch the new data, updating the state will be reflected in your app automatically

Comment: Can you please give an example? I set a new state var which is equal to the data that I am fetching in the #data div and then inside the function I am setting the state var to null but nothing happens. Does React give the possibility like in JQuery to do smt like this: $("#data").load(location.href+" #data>*",""); ?

Comment: I edited again my code. Can u please give me a hint?

Comment: I would recommend you to drop that forceUpdate call and instead of copying your state to a separate variable, use the state directly in your jsx

Answer (score 0):

1. Your products variable is not referencing any property from the state. Just call it directly in the JSX as Adrian mentioned.
2. You need to wrap your JSX within a common div.
3. I am assuming your button is not a component hence the change below. (If it is a component, then please post that component as well in your question and I'll update this answer accordingly).
4. Your render is not returning anything as it is. You need to your render to **return** your content.

---

Change the render section of your code to the following and let me know what you see in the console:

```
render() {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.refresh}>Refresh</button>
            <ListComponent
              data={this.state.products.map(entry => ({
                text: entry.productId
              }))}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

If the problem still persists, please post the `<ListComponent/>` part of the code as well as the complete code of the above component in your question too.