# Refresh a specific component 's data/ state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a List of products-ID and a button. When I press the button, I want to refresh the data in the ListComponent. I have no idea how can I do this in React. Can someone help me?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: this.props.productData //where productData an array of all products-ID
    };
    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
 }  


  refresh() {
    this.setState({ products: null });
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;
          <Button onClick={this.refresh} />
          <ListComponent
            data={products.map(entry => ({
              text: entry.productId
            }))}
          />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const products = selectAllProducts(state); //function that fetches-takes all products
  return {
    productData: products.map(products => ({
      productId: product.get("productId")
    }))
  };
};
```

Comment: You only should use `forceUpdate` if your `render` method depends on data other than state or props. In your case it's useless.

Comment: By "refresh the data" do you intend to set the products property to `null`? Or is there new data coming in from somewhere else?

Comment: @hindmost okay! can u give me a hint how will I refresh the data of ListComponent as I dont know?

Comment: _how will I refresh the data of ListComponent.._ It depends on where your data come from exactly.

Comment: @djfdev no. I dont want to set the products property to null. What I really want to do is to do a refresh because from somewhere else some new products may be added. I thought to set the state to null and then display the new state but this is not a good way. Do u have any idea how will I refresh the data?

Comment: Can you share where and how the new products are added? Are you saying that the props received by your component will change?

Comment: @hindmost see my code. I updated it.

Comment: @djfdev see my code above. Yes, they may get updated by a "third-party-app". But we dont care about this "third-party-app". I just need to refresh the new data in the ListComponent. See the mapToStateProps func.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is ... does your Redux state get updated from elsewhere in your application? Or is the refresh button supposed to fetch the new data from somewhere?

Comment: @djfdev The refresh button is supposed to fetch the new data from somewhere.

Comment: You _**should not**_ do any _fetching_ in `mapStateToProps`. It's only for mapping state to props.

Comment: @hindmost I am doing that. Please see my code carefully.

Comment: You got me wrong. You have to move that fetching call to the constructor or `componentDidMount`. It should not be in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload a part of page using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613380/reload-a-part-of-page-using-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your refresh function needs to call an action that fetches the data, and updates the Redux store accordingly. And because you've mapped part of your Redux state to this component's props, it will re-render when that data is fetched and saved via the reducer.

Therefore, you don't need to set local state at all in this component. Provided you have an action called `fetchProductData`:

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this)
  }

  // if you don't already have the data in your store, you can fetch it here to kick things off
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchProductData()
  }

  refresh () {
    this.props.fetchProductData()
  }

  render () {
    const { products } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.refresh} />
        <ListComponent
          data={products.map(entry => ({
            text: entry.productId
          }))}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const products = selectAllProducts(state)
  return {
    productData: products.map(products => ({
      productId: product.get("productId")
    }))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchProductData })(MyComponent)
```

Again, this assumes that `fetchProductData` dispatches an action that will update the redux state where products are stored. Passing the action to `connect` like this will make it available as a prop within the component.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've placed your `refresh()` inside the constructor, try:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: this.props.productData //where productData an array of all products-ID
    };
    this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
}

refresh() {
  this.setState({ products: null });
  this.forceUpdate();
}

render() {
  const { products } = this.state;
        <Button onClick={this.refresh} />
        <ListComponent
          data={products.map(entry => ({
            text: entry.productId
          }))}
        />
  );
}
```

I made a minimal component that does what you want it to do. Instead of binding in the constructor i use a fat arrow function for refresh.

```
import { Component } from "react";

const ListItem = props => props.item.text;

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [{ id: 0, text: "zero" }, { id: 1, text: "one" }]
    };
  }

  refresh = () => {
    this.setState({ items: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {items.map(i => (
          <div key={i.id}>
            <ListItem item={i} />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.refresh}>refresh</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

You don't need to `forceUpdate()`, the component will re-render by default when its props are changed.

For an explanation of the fat arrow and what it does to `this`, check out https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4.

Comment: that was not the problem. that was a copy paste error by me. the this.forceUpdate() does not work.

Comment: I updated my answer with a minimal component that does what you're asking. @KathrineHanson